# System.Type.Missing or System.Reflection.Missing.Value when working with Office PIA?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, system.type

I searched [these SO results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=missing&page=1&tab=relevance) and couldn't find anything related to my question. I doubt this could be a duplicate.

I'm currently writing a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel PIA wrapper in .NET C# 3.5 and was wondering about what is best to use while calling methods like opening a given workbook.

[`System.Type.Missing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.missing.aspx) or [`Missing.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.missing.value.aspx)?

I have performed a few Google searches, and can't find any difference, except that one is from the `System` namespace (*System.Type.Missing*), and the other (*Missing.Value*) comes from the `System.Reflection` namespace.

1. What is the major difference, if any, between both?
2. Under which circumstances one is best to use than the other?
3. Why is this so?

Both seem to be used when you want to pass a parameter's default value to the interop assembly...

Thanks for your answers! =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are the same. In the static initializer of `Type`, the field `Missing` is set to `System.Reflection.Missing.Value`.

As for why there are two ways of getting at the same value: who knows. It's quite likely that this is a backward compatibility remnant, as `Type.Missing` is typed as `object`, whereas `Missing.Value` is typed `Missing`.

Comment: Where did you find that they were actually the same, and more interestingly, where did you find out that Type.Missing was set to Missing.Value? Thanks! =)

Comment: There's this wonderful tool called Reflector :-) This allows you to look at the (compiled) code of every .NET assembly. But you can also try using ILDASM (part of the SDK) and look at the **.cctor** of  **Type**. It's the very first statement.